# featureCounts segmentation fault on Arch Linux

Tags: rna-seq, sam, subread, featurecounts

I am encountering a segmentation fault when attempting to run [featureCounts](http://bioinf.wehi.edu.au/featureCounts/) from `subread-1.6.3` on even small test data. I installed featureCounts from [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/subread/files/subread-1.6.3/) using the precompiled Linux binary.

Most existing help threads on this topic ([1](http://seqanswers.com/forums/showthread.php?t=50353), [2](https://www.biostars.org/p/169712/), [3](https://support.bioconductor.org/p/59473/)) show some splash screen output before the error, but I get a segmentation fault before any error is shown.

```
$ featureCounts -T 1 -p -t exon -g gene_id -a /data/sai/annots/musmus_cdna_all_ensembl92.gtf -o test.txt test.bam test2.bam
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved this problem by installing from source; I assume the precompiled binary was not compatible with the Arch Linux kernel.

Comment: I encountered this with several tools on arch. It looks like most tools are compatible with Ubuntu (or Debian in general) or biolinux

Comment: Perhaps the authors should note the distribution of the binary build rather than denoting it as "linux"... or perhaps I shouldn't be so naive as to think such a thing could exist ;)